# Scroll function on hover won't work unless resizing screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I miss 1% to finish my script, I just don't know how to do it :D

When you hover over the target to the left, you can see the image will scroll. But after clicking on a new image it won't. I then have to resize the window to make it work again. How to fix that? Below is my code but for a working example, [here's a CodePen](https://codepen.io/Cadima-io/pen/VGjeEw)

```js
(function($) {
  // virables
  var layoutContainer = '.container';
  var layoutTarget = '#target';
  var layoutTargetIMG = '#target img';
  var layoutIMG = '.container .gallery .item img';
  var layoutIMGFirst = '.container .gallery .item:first-child img';


  // Add first image to target 
  $(layoutIMGFirst).clone().appendTo(layoutTarget);

  // Add image to target when click on gallery image
  $(layoutIMG).click(function() {
    $(this).closest(layoutContainer).find(layoutTarget).empty();
    $(this).clone().appendTo(
      $(this).closest(layoutContainer).find(layoutTarget)
    );
  });



  // Image scroll on hover
  // This won't work after clicking on an image unless resizing the browser
  $(window).resize(function() {
    // If i remove this it won't work on the start image.
    // Any other solution?
    setTimeout(function() {

      $('#target img').each(function() {
        var itemHeight = $('#target').outerHeight();
        var imgHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
        // Work out what percentage the image is of the item and remove 100% from that
        var topHeight = (imgHeight / itemHeight) * 100 - 100;
        //Make the animation speed proptional to that ratio
        var animationSpeed = (imgHeight / itemHeight) / 1; //change 2 to tweak the speed

        $(this).css({
          transition: 'all ease ' + animationSpeed + 's'
        });

        $(this).mouseleave(function() {
          $(this).css({
            top: '0'
          });
        })

        // The 'top' property  of the image needs 
        // to be set as as a percentage of the parent
        $(this).mouseenter(function(e) {
          $(this).css({
            top: '-' + topHeight + '%',

          });
        })
      });
    }, 200);
  });


  $(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() { // Add delay after resize so function will load
      $(window).triggerHandler('resize');
    }, 200);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-left: -40px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 20px;
  .column {
    flex: 1;
    min-width: 30%;
    margin-left: 40px;
    .target {
      height: 400px;
      background: pink;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
    .cta {
      display: flex;
      a {
        background: lightgreen;
        width: 50%;
        padding: 16px 8px;
        ;
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        &:last-child {
          background: orange;
        }
      }
    }
    .gallery {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      margin-left: -4px;
      .item {
        flex: 1;
        margin-left: 4px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        &::before {
          content: '';
          padding-top: 80%;
          display: block;
        }
        img {
          position: absolute;
          min-width: 100%;
          min-height: 100%;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          cursor: pointer;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div id="target" class="target"></div>
    <div class="cta">
      <a href="#" class="demo">SE DEMO</a>
      <a href="#" class="buy">KØB LAYOUT</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="gallery">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/1200" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/1600" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/2000" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Keviin, I've requested a change to your question to include the code you wrote on CodePen. Even though the view isn't correct on Stack Overflow, this way if your CodePen is deleted in the future, anyone coming across your question will still be able to see the original code. You can read more about [runnable code snippets here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets).

Comment: Okay Super :) 
I'll compile the scss and see if it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this

```
$(layoutIMG).click(function() {
      $(this).closest(layoutContainer).find(layoutTarget).empty();
      $(this).clone().appendTo(
        $(this).closest(layoutContainer).find(layoutTarget)
      );
    });
```

to

```
$(layoutIMG).click(function() {
      $(this).closest(layoutContainer).find(layoutTarget).empty();
      $(this).clone().appendTo(
        $(this).closest(layoutContainer).find(layoutTarget)
      );
      $(window).triggerHandler('resize'); // added this line
    });
```

Comment: No Problem. Happy coding ! :)